# mysql:identify data input to show another data

Tags: mysql, match

dear all..i have a complicated case that must be have some troubleshoot.

i have some input form which connected to input data table.

```
<input type="text" id="model" name="model"/>
<input type="text" id="serial" name="serial"/>
<input type="text" id="lot" name="lot"/>
<input type="text" id="line" name="line"/>
```

i have one table like:

```
Model          Range_serial         lot        line
XD              1-100               11a        2
```

i want if i type `XD` in `#model` then `5` at `#serial`, i can show `11a` at `#lot` and `2` at `#line`.

it means, script read data from `$('#model').val()` and `$('#serial').val()` then send and match them with DB. if match lot and line data can show.

i still confuse too in identify number `5` from `1-100`. i need your guidance for resolve this case. may be any opinion will take me to advance.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood

matching for model value no problem

and for Range_serial match Use ***between*** keyword of mysql in query  for match range
 1 - 100

And show matched lot and line data using jquery.

Comment: select lot,line from tablename where left(range_serial,1) > $Value and right(range_serial,3) < $value

Answer (score 0):

use:

> select lot,line from tablename where
>   left(range_serial,1) > $Value and
>   right(range_serial,3) < $value

and for more generalize

find position of `"-"` using `INSTR()` function and use that position in query for finding left and right values using `substring()` function of mysql

Comment: block your answer then press ctrl+k

Comment: What u mean by block answer ?

Comment: to separate the code with text.look at my quetion the code look like separate with the text.